# What is the best way to display HTML content using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a php function as shown below, which takes in an array that has values from an SQL query (in another, not shown function). In this case, the SQL query returns a set of filenames and their associated picture names.

```
// Take in an array of filters;
// each element is a dictionary of column name 
// to the value of that row from SQL query
function displayFilters($filters) {
    foreach($filters as $filter){
        //output images in img tags, with their appropriate classes
        echo "  <div class='w3-quarter'>
                    <div class='w3-card-2'>
                        <img src='images/".$filter['File_Name']."' style='width:100%'>
                            <div class='w3-container'>
                                <h4>".$filter['Filter_Name']."</h4>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>";
    }

}
```

Now, this works fine and will properly display the images as I want. However, I keep having to modify this code, change classes, properties and what not, and if I need to add/modify to the div, I have to go into this function to change everything. Is there a better way to do this than going into the echo function to change it? I'd rather not have to use Javascript if possible, but if that is the only clean way to do it, can someone point me to a way to do this?

Comment: pass params in function ...

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify? Are you saying I should do something like pass the actual HTML string in as parameter, which is set somewhere else in the PHP code (and thus easier to modify)?

Comment: What this sounds like you are saying, is when i need to change my code i need to change my code.  We need more information as to what is wrong.  An example of what you want and what you get would help

Comment: Alright. What I'm saying is - is there a cleaner way of changing everything except what is passed in - basically, what the images are wrapped in - than going into the PHP function itself to do this? Is there a way to refactor this that's better? Eventually I expect the HTML code in this function to be a lot longer.

Comment: i expect, u need like that: yourfunction(param1,param2) or yourfunction(an array params)

Comment: I don't think you understand - this function is currently working perfectly. The problem is that the HTML that is being echoed is going to be changed a lot, and get much longer - I'd like to be able to put most of this code into the actual HTML of the page if possible and ONLY echo the filenames and picture names into the divs, but this is hard because I don't know beforehand how many images I will be returning.

Comment: You could use a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) to make your life easier on this matter.

Comment: This looks helpful, thank you. It looks like a lot to work with & install on my current GoDaddy account, but I will keep this option in mind.

Comment: I agree with @budwiser, [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) is a very good templating engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use a PHP Template Engine

---

http://www.smarty.net/

> Smarty is fast and lean with a small memory footprint.

---

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/ *(Looks remarkably like Dwoo)*

> Twig is a modern template engine for PHP (Fast, Secure, Flexible)

---

http://dwoo.org/ *(Inspired by Smarty)*

> Dwoo is a templating system used to make creating websites easier and more structured.

---

http://platesphp.com/ *(Inspired by Twig)*

> Plates is a native PHP template system that’s fast, easy to use and easy to extend.

---

http://phptal.org/

> PHPTAL is a PHP implementation of ZPT work. To be short, PHPTAL is a XML/XHTML template library for PHP.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php    function displayFilters($filters) {
            foreach($filters as $filter){ ?>
                //output images in img tags, with their appropriate classes
                <div class='w3-quarter'>
                            <div class='w3-card-2'>
                                <img src='images/<?=$filter['File_Name']>' style='width:100%'>
                                    <div class='w3-container'>
                                        <h4><?=$filter['Filter_Name']></h4>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<?php
            }

        } ?>
```

I do it this way and it seems easy than learning a new template engine

Answer (score 1):

I have written how to retrieve query and how to display in below code.
You can use this one.  you can also use image tag within table `<tr>` tag.

```
  $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','databasename');
  $sql="SELECT  `COL 1` ,  `COL 2` ,  `COL 3` ,  `COL 4` ,  `COL 5` ,  `COL 12` FROM  `TABLE` WHERE 1 ORDER BY  `COL 3`  ;";
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


<table style="width:100%"  >
 <tr>
 <th>Col1</th>
 <th>Clo2</th> 
 <th>Col3</th>
  </tr>

<?
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{

      echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."\t".$row[2]."\t".$row[3]."\t".$row[4]."</td><td>".$row[5]."</td></tr>";  
 }

?>

     </table>
```

Comment: I don't think you read my post very well. I've got the images displaying correctly. The problem is that they need to be formatted inside divs with very specific (but the same for all) styling, which takes up a lot of space and make it a very ugly, long php function that is mostly HTML output formatting - there must be a better way.

Comment: could you please refer to some link. How do you want to display images within div?

Comment: here  <div class='w3-container'> is part of <div class='w3-card-2'> and image displayed in 100% width. (that could be a problem).

Comment: Why would that be a problem? It's currently displaying properly.

Amarinder: I'm displaying images within the div because they need to be styled properly along with the title.

Comment: without using div tag you can display image using table.       echo "<tr> <img src='images/".$filter['File_Name']."' style='width:100%'></tr>";